# How to require a local package that depends on other local package

Tags: php, git, composer-php

A have the following folders, each one containing a project:

```
PackageA
PackageB
PackageC
```

**PackageA** depends on **PackageB** witch also depends on **PackageC**, each one is a git repository.

This is the **PackageA** composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "packagea/packagea",
    "require": {
         "packageb/packageb": "dev-master"
    }
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../PackageB"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the **PackageB** composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "packageb/packageb",
    "require": {
         "packagec/packagec": "dev-master"
    }
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../PackageC"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the **PackageC** composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "packagec/packagec"
}
```

This is what i get when i try `composer update` on PackageA folder:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for packageb/packageb dev-master -> satisfiable by packageb/packageb[dev-master].
>       - packageb/packageb dev-master requires packagec/packagec dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

But, there's a **PackageC** dependency specified on **PackageB**

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main trick with private dependencies is that entries `composer` finds in `repositories` are not shared across whole tree. So if you have your `project`, which requires `package A` from VCS, then your `project` needs to include proper entry in own `composer.json`'s `repositories` section. This is pretty obvious, but now imagine said `package A` requires `package B` from different private repository. So you add what's needed to `package B` `composer.json`'s `repositories` but while i.e. unit tests of that package works fine you still will be failing when trying to include that component in your `project`, same way you described. It's all because of these dependency sources. The not-so-obvious solution is to include all private repositories in your `project`'s `composer.json` - even if it is not directly needed or used. In other words, your `project`'s `composer.json` must include entries for VCS repositories as needed by all packages it includes, `package A` and `package B` (and so on). In your case you need to make it looke like that:

```
{
    "name": "packagea/packagea",
    "require": {
         "packageb/packageb": "dev-master"
    }
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../PackageB"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../PackageC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- packageb/packageb dev-master requires packagec/packagec dev-master -> satisfiable by packagec/packagec[dev-master].
- packageb/packageb dev-master requires packagec/packagec dev-master -> satisfiable by packagec/packagec[dev-master].

 - Removal request for packagec/packagec == 9999999-dev

 - Installation request for packageb/packageb dev-master -> satisfiable by packagec/packagec[dev-master].

Comment: This is what is missing in your answer to be the solution of my problem: "minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true

Comment: Please, added these lines to your answer, so i can mark as **answer**, and very thanks! :)

Comment: You may not need `minimum-stability` set at all, if you required i.e. `dev-master` version explicitely